# Notify JSF Server side about changes on (DOM) client-state made by Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, dom, jsf-2, rich-client-platform

Using a component based Framework like JSF, a component for a checkbox get defined:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{user.favNumber1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Number1 - 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Number1 - 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

the generated (x-html) code looks like:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:0" value="1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:0" class=""> Number1 - 1</label></td>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:1" class=""> Number1 - 2</label></td>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:2" class=""> Number1 - 3</label></td>
  <td>
</tr>
</table>
```

a Jquery function changes the state of this component (let say the box with value "1") on one event(the click of "button"):

```
<script>  // or in $(document).ready(){}
   $('#button').click(function(){ 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find('#j_idt6:j_idt10:0');
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
   });
</script>
```

how do I notify the JSF-side that the client state changed. at this level JSF still thinks 
that the checkbox has e.g value 0 whereas it has now value 1.  this leads to state inconsistency...

what are my options?

I think of the AJAX- support of JSF  on other (Rich-, Primes-, MyFaces) but I still relent to use it, knowing that 
to have my component to update , because I am building a rich client with many features 
(Display manipulation, Jquery UI widgets, Web remoting, dynamic behaviour, Web-services, visual effects , and so on ). the DOM client state in supposed to heavily manipulated and Jquery is something that is a must.. so it can't be left aside.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using JSF2 you should use [f:ajax](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/) (google some more about it)

Like this (no jquery needed in your case)

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{user.favNumber1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Number1 - 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Number1 - 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{user.someMethod}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

where in your `user` bean

```
public void someMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
    System.out.println(favNumber1);
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, but the requirements are to use Jquery, not only for the checkbox alone but for other page elements... I just gave above a´n example of  a larger problem

Comment: Are you looking for a way to pass data from js to server using the jsf ajax ?

Comment: I am looking for a way to notify the server if a component's state get change , knowing that Jquery makes the change. Still looking for it.

Comment: in that case you should plant `f:ajax` in those jsf components and then call `$('#someID').change();` or `$('#someID').click();` on those jsf components to trigger their ajax behavior that will inform the server